# JQuery addClass not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
$("div#pay-by-this-method ul li a").click(function(){
  $("div#pay-by-this-method ul li").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected");
});

<div id="pay-by-this-method" class="append-bottom">
<ul id="payment-method-chooser">
    <li id="" class=""><a href="#" rel="" class="" >Credit/Debit Card</a></li>
    <li id="" class=""><a href="#" rel="" class="">Net 30 Account</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
```

This function applies to two links. The first link is chosen by default and has the 'selected' class already chosen. The removeClass works when I click the other link, but addClass does not fire for the other link, nor when i click the first link again (it should).

I don't see any reason why this function would not be working, there's not much to it. Am I missing something here?

BTW, there is more code (an if else statement I can't post publicly) inside the function as well that is working just fine. i can fire alerts and pretty much do anything else in this function and it works perfectly. The removeClass works fine, too, it's just the addClass that isn't firing.

Comment: what happens if you remove "li" as the argument to the .parent() ?

Comment: added the code. unfortunately i had to strip out anything that might be helpful, i think. proprietary stuff, sorry!

Comment: seems to work ok: http://jsfiddle.net/WvnU8/

Comment: hmm. yeah, it does. sadly, it's not working on my dev server. i'm guessing i've got some other conflict or something elsewhere. well, at least i've clarified this much. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You may want

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
```

The ".parent()" function only applies to the *direct* parent of an element, and when you pass it a selector that doesn't match the actual parent you get an empty jQuery list.  The ".closest()" function finds the first ancestor that matches the selector, no matter how far up the DOM it is.

Comment: great bit of helpful information, thank you! unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem. it's functioning exactly the same.